# A solution to de-seasonalizing data? Admission rate to emergency room

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, stata, seasonality

I am trying to fit a model for the admission rate to our emergency department by using time series in STATA, which is fairly new to me and I would like to take your input about deseasonalizing. data:[datafile](https://easyupload.io/u97pz5)

The data consists of 2 years of univariate data with weekly seasonality, where Saturdays and Sundays show more admission as seen in the image below.

[image: seven weekdays boxplots of time series]

To overcome this 7 day seasonality, first I differenced by 7 and built the model with `d=7`. But the residuals failed to show white noise with portmanteau test. SARIMA model with 7 days differencing resulted in the same
behavior but I modeled with regression analysis with seasonal dummy variables: `d1-d7` for 7 days of week (thanks to Prof Hansen and his [lecture](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/390/390Lecture14.pdf)):

```
regress totalhasta d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 L(1/7).VAR_NAME, noconstant
```

The residuals show white noise and model shows better fit with lower AIC and BIC tests compared to other 2 models.

So is it a good practice to use dummy variables instead of differencing with the seasonality length, SARIMA models to overcome seasonality?

Answer (score 3):

As nobody more experienced with time series is answering, I will give a try. First, you should tell us clearer what is your goal---prediction or description/estimation of seasonalities. If goal is prediction, I think seasonalities should be part of the model, you should not deseasonalize first. As you have daily data, tou could find much information [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=daily+data&sites=https%3A%2F%2Frobjhyndman.com&k7=%23faf8f8&kj=%23b33&ky=%23fafafa&kx=b&ko=-1&k1=-1&ia=web).  But, in all cases I would start with visualization to understand the data better.

```
dta <- readstata13::read.dta13("veriseti min 13 03 2020.dta")

library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)

dta <- as_tsibble(dta)
```

[image]

produced by `gg_season(dta, period=7)`.  A subseries plot can be helpful:

[image]

produced by `dta %>% gg_subseries(period=7)`. This plot makes it clear that the series is not stationary, it is a dip around the mid of the time period. A Seasonal decomposition made by `dta %>% model(STL(pt  ~ season(period=7))) %>% components() %>% autoplot()`:

[image]

It is interesting that the spread of the seasonal component seems to be diminishing somewhat.